# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a react project. I'm using pouchdb-browser to save the data from the form. Now I want to retrieve the data on a table but getting

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined
```

I'm using the below files:

form.js

```
'use strict'

import React from 'react'
import GradeInfo from 'GradeInfo'


export default class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.submitInfo = this.submitInfo.bind(this)
    this.schoolDb = this.props.schoolDb
  }

  submitInfo (event) {
    event.preventDefault()

    let gradeInfo = Object.assign({}, this.props.grade)

    if (!gradeInfo._id) {
      gradeInfo._id = gradeInfo.id
    }

    console.log('About to post to pouch...', gradeInfo._id)

    // Save to pouchdb
    this.schoolDb.put(gradeInfo, (err, result) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log('Successfully posted to pouchdb!')
        this.props.clearCurrentGrade()
      } else {
        console.log('Error saving to pouch...')
        console.log(err)
      }
    })
  }



  render () {
    let {
      grade,
      edit,
      updateGrade,
      updateGradeState,
    } = this.props
    return (
      <div className='row'>
        <div className='columns large-centered large-12  medium-12'>
          <div className='form'>
            <div className='container'>
        <form action='' onSubmit={this.submitInfo}>
          <div className='student-form__container'>
          <GradeInfo edit={edit} handleChange={updateGrade('GradeInfo')} {...grade.GradeInfo} />
          <button className='button expanded' type='submit'>Save</button>
          </div>
        </form>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Data.js
This is where I retrieve the data:

```
import React from 'react'

export default class Data extends React.Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {grades: []}
    this.schoolDb = this.props.schoolDb
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.updateGrades()
    this.schoolDb.changes({
      since: 'now',
      live: true
    }).on('change', (change) => {
      this.updateGrades()
    }).on('error', (err) => {
      console.error(err)
    })
  }

  updateGrades () {
    this.schoolDb.allDocs({include_docs: true}).then((res) => {
      var grades = res.rows.map((row) => row.gradeInfo)
      this.setState({grades})
    })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className='eidsr-data'>
        <div className='eidsr-data__header'>
          <h3 className='eidsr-data__title'>Grades Overview</h3>
        </div>
        <div className='table-list'>
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Student ID</th>
                <th>Semester</th>
                <th>Period</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
              {this.state.grades.map((gradeInfo) => <DataRow key={gradeInfo._id} gradeInfo={gradeInfo} {...this.props} />)}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class DataRow extends React.Component {
  render () {
    let {gradeInfo} = this.props

    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{gradeInfo.GradeInfo['studentID']}</td>
        <td>{gradeInfo.GradeInfo['semester']}</td>
        <td>{gradeInfo.GradeInfo['period']}</td>
      </tr>
    )
  }
}
```

And in I render like this in the main app.js file

```
<Data schoolDb={this.schoolDb} {...this.props}/>
```

I'm getting this error when I run the app and it's coming from Data.js

Comment: in which file are you getting an error and how can you please elaborate ?

Comment: I'm getting this error when I run the app and it's coming from Data.js

Comment: Are you sure you get docs in your query: "this.schoolDb.allDocs({include_docs: true})" Also It would better to control empty responses by doing something like "if (this.state.grades.length > 0) ..."

Comment: that might be the case when `this.schoolDb.allDocs({include_docs: true})` is not returning any gradeInfo since nothing was matching for the given query

Comment: This was actually the case, it's working now. I didn't have docs in my query. But I'm however getting another error. I don't save more than on document while the app is opened, it gives me this error: CustomPouchError
error
:
true
id
:
"8bf063c1-a371-4380-a1c9-6ddb6b30f08f"
message
:
"Document update conflict"
name
:
"conflict"
status
:
409 I have to restart the app before adding another info.

Answer (score 0):

When the following line executes:

```
{this.state.grades.map((gradeInfo) => <DataRow key={gradeInfo._id} gradeInfo={gradeInfo} {...this.props} />)}
```

`gradleInfo` hasn't been initialized. Hence the error.

## Fix

Initialize `gradleInfo` before rendering the component.